# Yii Framework, path to custom PHP file

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using [Yii Framework](http://yiiframework.com) and I have custom **.php** file with `header('Content-type: image/png');` Actually it returns an image.
I want in my **view** see that image this way:

```
<img src="path/to/custom/image.php"/>
```

Where should I **put** my custom php file? And how I should **set it's path**?

Comment: Why don't you put this code in a controller action ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative to your controller, example: `../../images/file.php`, or you can do this:

```
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/file.php"/>
```

In this way, the file must be accesible from outside.

Just to clarify, you shouldn't call this from your controller, but from your view.

Comment: I think this way would be nice. Thx

Comment: If you are going to call it from a view and the image comes from a controller action you should use `'controller/action'` url format using `createUrl()` from `CController`: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail

Comment: yeap, I've edited my question, not from controller but from view.